# How to close the qt application when setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false)

Tags: qt, multi-window

I wish to create a project including 3 windows: mainWindow, childWindow1, childWindow2, and only one window should show at a time. And I can switch between these windows.

So I have three tasks:

1. I place two buttons in the mainWindow and want to use them to make one of the child windows showing and the main window hiding.
2. And when I close the child window, I wish to show the main window.
3. When I close the main window, terminate the whole application.

I first had a problem:
If I close the child window, the application exit.
So I use the qApp.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false), and I got task 2 done.
But another problem occured:
If I close the main window, the program is still running.

Last problem:
How to show the child window in the task bar? It looks wired to run a program which can't be found in the taskbar.

I search everywhere I could, any help would be really appreciated!

main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  a.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
  MainWindow mainWindow;
  mainWindow.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

mainWindow.cpp:

```
void mainWindow::button1Clicked()
{
  this->hide();
  childWindow1 = new ChildWindow1(this);
  connect(childWindow1, &QMainWindow::destroyed, this, &QMainWindow::show);
  childWindow1->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
  childWindow1->show();
}
```

childWindow1.cpp

```
ChildWindow1::ChildWindow1(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
  ui.setupUi(this);
  setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
}
```

Comment: Don't you just need to override [`QWidget::closeEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent) in your `MainWindow` class (and possibly also  the child window classes)?

Comment: @G.M. Thank you! I solved the first problem! Here is the solution:1. comment `a.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);`; 2. overrride `QWidget::closeEvent`, and in closeEvent, `qobject_cast<QMainWindow*>(parent())->show(); event->accept();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to do the following:

1. In your `main.cpp`:

   ```
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   a.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
   MainWindow w;
   QObject::connect(&w, &MainWindow::exited, &a, &QApplication::quit);
   w.show();
   return a.exec();
   ```

`exited` signal  would be used to exit the application after closing the main window.

2. In your `MainWindow` you should reimplement `closeEvent` like this:

   ```
   void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
   {
       QMainWindow::closeEvent(event);
       emit exited();
   }
   ```

Don't forget to add `exited()` to `MainWindow` `signals` section;

3. Finally, code for creating new windows should be the following:

   ```
   child1 = new ChildWindow;
   child1->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
   connect(child1, &QObject::destroyed, this, &QWidget::show);
   child1->show();
   hide();
   ```

Note that I don't pass `this` as a parent for a `ChildWindow`, this allows it to appear in the task bar.

So, creating a new `ChildWindow` will hide the main window, closing the `ChildWindow` will delete it automatically (that's another reason why you don't need to pass parent to `ChildWindow` constructor) and closing `MainWindow` will close the whole application thanks to our `exited` signal.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly! So I got 2 answers to solve my problem: 1. `setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(true);`, reimplement `closeEvent` in 2 ChildWindow, and show mainWindow before processing close event; 2. `setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);`, reimplement `closeEvent` in MainWindow, and emit a signal to terminate the application.

Comment: `qobject_cast<QMainWindow*>(parent())->show();` is not the best idea as long as `parent` can be `nullptr`. For example in my solution it is.